# Confusion over Private vs Public IPFS Pin Orchestration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipfs

I am working on an application that requires IPFS storage. I am looking for a highly available and fast IPFS Pinning service that can store large file sizes.

I’ve been looking into services like Pinata, IPFS Cluster, Temporal, and Infura—which does not support large file sizes).

1. I have some confusion over a Private vs Public IPFS network. Are files stored in the IPFS cluster accessible to anyone outside of the cluster’s network?
2. Are there any opinions on IPFS cluster vs Pinata?

Answer (score 0):

IPFS nodes (hosted, cluster or otherwise) can be configured to connect to the public IPFS DHT or only to nodes you specify.

The latter option is considered a private network. A summary of this approach is here, with links to documentation:

https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/privacy/#creating-a-private-network

Hosted private networks: I do not know whether Pinata offers private networks as a service.

IPFS Cluster: You do not necessarily need IPFS Cluster for this use-case. You can simply configure all participating IPFS nodes to participate in the private network.